# Realm accessed from incorrect thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, realm

I'm using serial GCD queue to work with realm. Application crashes with `Realm accessed from incorrect thread` exception when GCD starts to switch threads for the queue. Is there any way to bind given realm with a thread using GCD API?

Here's a quick example

```
self.realmQueue = dispatch_queue_create("db", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);

__block RLMRealm *realm = nil;
dispatch_async(self.realmQueue, ^{
    realm = [RLMRealm realmWithPath:[NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"temp"]];
});

self.motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
self.motionManager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 0.001;
__block int i = 0;
__block BOOL shouldBeginWriteTransaction = YES;

[self.motionManager startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] withHandler:^(CMAccelerometerData *accelerometerData, NSError *error) {

    dispatch_async(self.realmQueue, ^{
        if (shouldBeginWriteTransaction) {
            [realm beginWriteTransaction];
            shouldBeginWriteTransaction = NO;
        }

        AccelerationEvent *event = [[AccelerationEvent alloc] init];
        event.x = accelerometerData.acceleration.x;
        event.y = accelerometerData.acceleration.x;
        event.z = accelerometerData.acceleration.y;
        event.time = [NSDate date];
        [realm addObject:event];

        if (i % 1000) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                self.xLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", event.x];
                self.yLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", event.y];
                self.zLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", event.z];
            });
        }

        if (i % 10000 == 0) {
            NSDate *startDate = [NSDate date];
            [realm commitWriteTransaction];
            NSLog(@"save time: %f", [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:startDate]);
            shouldBeginWriteTransaction = YES;
        }

        i++;
    });
}];
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

[From Realm docs](http://realm.io/docs/cocoa/0.84.0/#background-operations): `RLMRealm` objects are not thread safe and cannot be shared across threads, so you must get an `RLMRealm` instance in each thread/dispatch_queue in which you want to read or write.

[Also from Realm docs](http://realm.io/docs/cocoa/0.84.0/api/Classes/RLMRealm.html#//api/name/defaultRealm): `RLMRealm` objects are cached internally by Realm, and calling this method multiple times on a single thread within a single iteration of the run loop will normally return the same `RLMRealm` object.

So knowing this, I modified your code sample to get the `RLMRealm` directly from the `dispatch_async` block where it is used, without incurring a performance penalty, since it is cached.

I also noticed that an `AccelerationEvent` was passed across threads, which is also not allowed. So this modified code sample passes `NSString`s across threads instead.

```
self.realmQueue = dispatch_queue_create("db", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);

self.motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
self.motionManager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 0.001;
__block int i = 0;
__block BOOL shouldBeginWriteTransaction = YES;

[self.motionManager startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] withHandler:^(CMAccelerometerData *accelerometerData, NSError *error) {

    dispatch_async(self.realmQueue, ^{
        RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm realmWithPath:[NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"temp"]];
        if (shouldBeginWriteTransaction) {
            [realm beginWriteTransaction];
            shouldBeginWriteTransaction = NO;
        }

        AccelerationEvent *event = [[AccelerationEvent alloc] init];
        event.x = accelerometerData.acceleration.x;
        event.y = accelerometerData.acceleration.x;
        event.z = accelerometerData.acceleration.y;
        event.time = [NSDate date];
        [realm addObject:event];

        if (i % 1000) {
            NSString *xString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", event.x];
            NSString *yString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", event.y];
            NSString *zString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", event.z];
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                self.xLabel.text = xString;
                self.yLabel.text = yString;
                self.zLabel.text = zString;
            });
        }

        if (i % 10000 == 0) {
            NSDate *startDate = [NSDate date];
            [realm commitWriteTransaction];
            NSLog(@"save time: %f", [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:startDate]);
            shouldBeginWriteTransaction = YES;
        }

        i++;
    });
}];
```

I haven't run this code to confirm that it works, so let me know if this still doesn't resolve the issue.

Comment: @jpsim from what you said, I thought only RLMRealm is not thread-safe, it turns out that all RLMObject subclasses got from that realm are not thread-safe, too

Comment: From Realm's documentation: "you can only use an object on the thread which it was created, and you can’t access its ivars directly for any persisted properties." https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#models