# Correct Method for Realm.io with GCD?

Tags: ios8, grand-central-dispatch, realm

I was wondering if this is the desired method for concurrency with GCD and realm.io. I'm receiving a "Realm accessed from incorrect thread error", both are writing to the same Realm, but according to the documentation, this is allowed?

```
RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
NSString *username = @"username3";
NSString *realmPath = realm.path;

dispatch_queue_t remote_registration_queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0);
dispatch_async(remote_registration_queue, ^(void) {
    [KUser remoteRegisterUsername:username realmPath:realmPath];
});

dispatch_queue_t local_registration_queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0);
dispatch_async(local_registration_queue, ^(void) {
    [KUser localRegistrationWithUsername:self.username password:password realmPath:realmPath];
});
```

Within each method, I'm calling:

```
RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm realmWithPath:realmPath];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Realm accessed from incorrect thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25661023/realm-accessed-from-incorrect-thread)

Comment: Where do the docs claim that you should be able to have R/W access to the same file concurrently from multiple threads? That doesn't strike me as something that would be reasonable to expect unless they explicitly claimed to support it.

Comment: To access the same Realm file from different threads, you must call [RLMRealm defaultRealm], [RLMRealm realmWithPath:] or [RLMRealm realmWithPath:readOnly:error:] to get a different Realm object for every thread of your app. As long as you specify the same path, all RLMRealm objects will map to the same file on disk.

Sharing RLMRealm instances across threads is not supported.
RLMRealm instances accessing the same realm file must also all use the same readOnly value (either all readwrite, or all readonly).

Comment: That does not imply (to me) that you can use them concurrently for R/W access.

Comment: By "access", I think it's a reasonable inference to assume "R/W", if not they would have specified that. From there, it's first-order logical consequence.

Comment: @user1447447 could you possible share more of the code surrounding you usage of Realm? It would make diagnosing the issue much easier.

Comment: Added more, this is all in the single view controller. Within each of the KUser methods, I call [RLMRealm realmWithPath:] and perform write operations on the same object.

Comment: Yeah, having read more in depth, it appears Realm.io does indeed support concurrent access with just a few restrictions. Please forgive my knee-jerk skepticism. :)

Comment: No worries! I've actually decided to go away from Realm, curious how you feel about it if you've used it - it looked good from the outside, but Yap was the better route for the concurrency model that I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it without passing the Realm's path?

I believe the proper way would be to use `RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];` in each of the methods to get a reference to the proper Realm. No need to worry about the path.

So you should be able to reduce the code you first referenced to:

```
NSString *username = @"username3";

dispatch_queue_t remote_registration_queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0);
dispatch_async(remote_registration_queue, ^(void) {
    [KUser remoteRegisterUsername:username];
});

dispatch_queue_t local_registration_queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0);
dispatch_async(local_registration_queue, ^(void) {
    [KUser localRegistrationWithUsername:self.username password:password];
});
```

Comment: Yeah that didn't work, but I wanted the ability to specify another path anyway, and it shouldn't matter. If the default Realm is really the only realm that you can access concurrently, they should specify that in docs. For what it's worth, I've moved from Realm to Yap -> loved the concept of Realm, but a lot of the design decisions I disagreed with. For instance, if they wanted a PONSO model, it's really counterintuitive that you can only edit within a transaction, that RLMObjects aren't thread-safe, etc.