# Realm Swift iOS - Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Realm accessed from incorrect thread'

Tags: ios, swift, object, exception, realm

I have a problem with loading objects from Realm Database in Swift 2.0.

I call:

```
    var cities = try! Realm().objects(City)
```

and my app crashes and I give 
"Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Realm accessed from incorrect thread"

Has anyone example code or tutorial when and where I should call methods ?

Comment: Method is called in global blocks, because i want have a global collection cities

Comment: Refer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25661023/realm-accessed-from-incorrect-thread

Comment: Can you share more of the code that's causing you problems? The brief snippet you've shared so far doesn't involve threads, so it's impossible to tell where things are going wrong.

Answer (score 6):

A realm, as well as most objects in that realm, can only be accessed from the thread that this realm was created on (i.e. the thread on which you did something like `let realm = Realm()`).

So when you create a realm `let realm = try Realm()` on 'thread A', you can only access this realm from 'thread A'. Otherwise, you get a RLMException.

Likewise for most objects, if you grab it from this realm on 'thread A', for example: `var myCars = realm.objects(Car.self)`, then you can only use your `myCars` object on 'thread A'.

A quick fix, but definitely not the best approach for a production quality app, is to just throw everything onto the main queue. This ensures that all of your realm stuff occurs on the same thread, but the downfall is that it **can significantly slow down your app** if you are doing some heavy lifting. In swift 3, you do this by:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async{
    do{
        //your stuff.
        //ex:
        let realm = try Realm()
        myCars = try realm.objects(Car.self)
        if myCars != nil{
            try realm.write{
                for car in myCars!{
                    car.drive()
                }
            }
        }
    }catch{
        print(error)
    }
}
```

A much **better solution** is to **use a background queue**, and then go back to the main queue when you need to update. You can create a background queue like this:

`let myRealmQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "realmQueue", qos: .background)`

And then do your realm stuff on this queue:

```
myRealmQueue.async{
    do{
        //Do your realm stuff in this queue.
        let realm = try Realm()
        myCars = try realm.objects(Car.self)
        if myCars != nil{
            let numberOfCars = myCars.count
            //return to main queue to update UI
            DispatchQueue.main.async{
                numberOfCarsLabel.text = numberOfCars
            }
        }
    }catch{
        print(error)
    }
}
```

If you are not very familiar with threading in swift, I recommend you spend at least an hour or two on google to familiarize yourself with best practices. Chances are you'll find a better solution than the one I've provided.

Comment: yes also and you can instantiate realm once and also and use it as a property of a class, also you may add the getter / setter of an object to use Realm internally, to drastically reduce repeated boilerplate code.