# Realm 1.0 How can I use thread

Tags: swift, multithreading, realm

I would like to use the realm in my project, but I have a very complex filter and sort. I have to order the list by name,but the name is in other class.

```
class CustomObject: Object
{
    dynamic var objectId = 0
    let objectLangs = List<ObjectLang>()
}

class ObjectLang: Object
{
    dynamic var objectId = 0
    dynamic var name = ""
}
```

When I have more than 130 rows, it is very slow in main thread and it blocks the UI. I tried do it in a background thread, but when I want to update the UI, it was crashed by Realm. So what is the perfect solution? How could I use it? Could you give me an example or tutorial? I have read the guide line.

Answer (score 0):

If program is crashed when updating UI on background thread, you should update UI on main thread when realm task finished.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), {
    let realm = try! Realm()

    //do What you need 

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        //updateUI()
    })
})
```

Comment: I updated on main thread, but I can't available the list of my object. I got a realm error.

Comment: can't you acess the list of object by realm? Or in memory? P.S. I'm beginner of stack overflow, so I can't add comment to your reply.

Comment: Do you add your object in write block? `try! realm.write {
                    realm.add(YourObejct)
                }`

Comment: OK. I found this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25661023/realm-accessed-from-incorrect-thread. I think you should get a realm instance when change the thread.

Comment: What is unmanaged copy? I found another solution. Using RealmDescription. https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1410

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Realm accessors across threads. You will need to retrieve the objects on the thread on which you want to use them. To make that happen, I'd recommend for each of your object classes which need to be passed between threads to designate a property as primary key. This property might be `objectId` in your case.

```
class CustomObject: Object {
    dynamic var objectId = 0
    let objectLangs = List<ObjectLang>()

    override class func primaryKey() -> String {
        return "objectId"
    }
}
```

This primary key can then be used to identify your objects and pass them over to the main thread to retrieve them there again.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0) {
    let realm = try! Realm()

    var objects = realm.objects(CustomObject)
    // objects = objects.filter(…)
    let sortedObjects: [CustomObject] = objects.sort { /* … */ }
    let ids = sortedObjects.map { $0.objectId }

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        let realm = try! Realm()
        let objects = ids.map {
            realm.objectForPrimaryKey(CustomObject.self, key: $0)
        }
        updateUIWithObjects(objects)
    }
}
```