# How to perform multiple asynchronous requests starting one after another

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, asynchronous, grand-central-dispatch

I have a set of requests that are performed asynchronous. However, each next request should only start when the previous request is finished (due to data dependency).

Since all requests should just be finished in the right order, `DispatchGroup()` seems of no use.

I currently implemented `DispatchSemaphore()`, but I feel that this is not the best solution since I want to assure that all requests are performed in the background.

```
let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: requests.count)

for request in requests {
    apiManager().performAsyncRequest(request, failure: { error in
        print(error); semaphore.signal()
        }) { print(“request finished successful”) 
        // Next request should be performed now
        semaphore.signal()
    }
}
semaphore.wait()
```

Is there a better way to perform this?

**Note**: based on implementation of one of the answers below I encountered that `apiManager()` is not thread safe (due to the use of a Realm database).

To keep this question clear and consider the answers in a thread safety manner with a thread safe definition of `performAsyncRequest`:

```
public func performAsyncRequest(_ requestNumber: Int, success: @escaping (Int) -> Void)->Void {
    DispatchQueue(label: "performRequest").async {
        usleep(useconds_t(1000-requestNumber*200))
        print("Request #\(requestNumber) starts")
        success(requestNumber)
    }
}
```

*Solution with `DispatchSemaphore`*

```
        let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 1)
        DispatchQueue(label: "requests").async {
            for requestNumber in 0..<4 {
                semaphore.wait()
                performAsyncRequest(requestNumber) { requestNumber in
                        print("Request #\(requestNumber) finished")
                        semaphore.signal()
                }
            }
        }
```

With the expected output:

```
Request #0 starts
Request #0 finished
Request #1 starts
Request #1 finished
Request #2 starts
Request #2 finished
Request #3 starts
Request #3 finished
```

*Unsuccessful try with `Operation`*

```
    var operations = [Operation]()

    for requestNumber in 0..<4 {
        let operation = BlockOperation(block: {
            performAsyncRequest(requestNumber) { requestNumber in
                DispatchQueue.main.sync {
                    print("Request #\(requestNumber) finished")
                }
            }
        })

        if operations.count > 0 {
            operation.addDependency(operations.last!)
        }
        operations.append(operation)
    }

    let operationQueue = OperationQueue.main
    operationQueue.addOperations(operations, waitUntilFinished: false)
```

With incorrect output:

```
Request #0 starts
Request #1 starts
Request #2 starts
Request #3 starts
Request #0 finished
Request #3 finished
Request #2 finished
Request #1 finished
```

My feeling is that it should also be possible to get this working with `Operation`, but I don't know whether it would be better than using `DispatchSemaphore`.

Comment: Which Swift version are you targeting?

Comment: Swift 3. I just edited the question with an implementation of DispatchSemaphore, but I am wondering whether it should be used at all in this situation.

Comment: What do you mean by "all requests are performed in the background"? If apiManager() is not thread safe it will not be possible to execute any call to performAsyncRequest on a background thread.

Comment: What I meant to say was “all request are performed async without blocking the UI”. Since apiManager() performs an Alamofire request inside, I assume that these request are performed in a background thread. However, fetching and processing the Realm data should be fetched from the main thread as becomes apparent from implementation of your answer.

Comment: Please, you should really address the thread safety issue in another question and leave this one to deal with the serial execution of the asynchronous calls. This way the answers will be more useful and clear for future users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track with the DispatchSemaphore to ensure that an asyncronous call is not started before the previous one has finished. I would just ensure that the code that manages the calls to the asyncronous API runs in the background:

```
let backgroundQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "requests")
let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 1)

backgroundQueue.async {
    var requestNumber = 1

    for request in requests {
        semaphore.wait()

        let currentRequestNumber = requestNumber

        print("Request launched #\(requestNumber)")

        apiManager().performAsyncRequest(request,
        failure: {
            error in
            print("Request error #\(currentRequestNumber)")
            semaphore.signal()
        }) {
            print("Request result #\(currentRequestNumber)")
            semaphore.signal()
        }

        requestNumber = requestNumber + 1
    }
}
```

The code will continue execution immediatelly while the for loop runs in a background loop and starts each request after waiting for the previous one to finish.

Or if apiManager() is not thread safe:

```
let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 1)

var requestNumber = 1

for request in requests {
    semaphore.wait()

    let currentRequestNumber = requestNumber

    print("Request launched #\(requestNumber)")

    apiManager().performAsyncRequest(request,
    failure: {
        error in
        print("Request error #\(currentRequestNumber)")
        semaphore.signal()
    }) {
        print("Request result #\(currentRequestNumber)")
        semaphore.signal()
    }

    requestNumber = requestNumber + 1
}
```

This has the limitation that the for loop will be in execution until the last request starts execution. But if the code you are calling is not thread safe there is no way around that.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not get this working. Due to an underlying Realm database the following error occurs: `terminating with uncaught exception of type realm::IncorrectThreadException: Realm accessed from incorrect thread.` Without the use of the background threat, however, the implementation results in a deadlock.

Comment: Currently, I am also working on an implementation using NSOperation as suggested in the other answer. Is this use case not better suited for `NSOperation` anyhow?

Comment: Please, change the question to clarify that apiManager is not thread safe, see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25670511/563802.

Comment: See my comment on that answer

Comment: I didn’t realized the thread unsafety before, but I will update the question. Hm.. it becomes somewhat more complex than expected. Any ideas to solve this issue? I appreciate your help on this…

Comment: Are you implementing a singleton in your code, or creating a Realm object and reusing it for multiple requests? Your trouble is probably there. In the example in the linked answer notice how the solution consists of a new object is being created for every asynchronous thread. If you store a Realm object to be reused by all requests you may not encounter any trouble if all your code runs in the same thread, but now it seems that you are creating the Realm object in one thread and then accessing it from a new background thread.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NSOperationQueue` and add each request as as operation

```
let firstOperation: NSOperation
let secondOperation: NSOperation
secondOperation.addDependency(firstOperation)

let operationQueue = NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()
operationQueue.addOperations([firstOperation, secondOperation], waitUntilFinished: false)
```

Comment: How does this answer address the requirement that one cal will not be started before the previous asynchronous call has finished?

Comment: @xpereta NSOperationQueue supports dependencies, here I''ve made secondOperation  dependent on the first one, so it won't start until first one is completed  https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/operation

Comment: In the question the call to performAsyncRequest is asyncronous and will complete immediately. The next request can't be started until the completion closure of the previous one has been executed.

Comment: @xpereta this was in response to earlier question and yes I believe we could do asynchronous operations.

Comment: I was unable use `(NS)Operation` appropriately (and therefore accepted the other answer), but I feel that this should work as well. I updated my question with an implementation using `Operation` in a more simple (thread safe) situation, but the requests seem to be processed in an incorrect order. Do you know what I do wrong? And do you possibly also know why this approach might be better than using `DispatchSemaphore`? Unfortunately, In my real application I also encounter problems with  `DispatchSemaphore` for which I asked a new question. Many thanks...

Comment: My new question was posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39898969/how-to-perform-asynchronous-requests-serially-in-combination-with-realm-and-alam?noredirect=1#comment67084647_39898969